# interactions involving two continuous predictors with emtrends

Tags: regression, mixed-model, interaction, multilevel-analysis, lsmeans

Let's say I have a model with two continuous predictors (`nitrogen and temperature`) and one categorical variable (`variety`).

```
dat <- data.frame(blocks=rep(c(1:15),each=2), variety=rep(c("A","B","C"),each=10),soil=runif(30,0,10), nitro = runif(30, 0, 10), temp= rnorm(30, 10, 3));

mod <- lmer(soil ~ variety*nitro*temp + (1|blocks), data=dat)
```

Let's pretend the `variety:nitro:temp` interaction is significant. How can I calculate the trend involving these two continuous predictors? For example maybe I believe that the slope between soil and nitrogen will be steeper at increasingly higher temperatures only in variety A. Or, in other words, how can I test if the slope between soil and nitrogen changes as a function of temperature in variety A?

I thought this would give me that information

```
> emtrends(mod, pairwise~variety, var=c("nitro","temp"))
```

but it throws an error

```
Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds
```

Answer (score 4):

The `var` argument specifies the variable whose slope you are interested in. Thus it can be only one character string, not a vector; in your case `nitro`.

The `at` argument allows you to specify values of other variables for which you wish do to tests and comparisons. `at` is a named list. In your case, to address the question you ask that would be:

```
emtrends(mod, pairwise ~ temp, var="nitro", at=list(variety="A", temp=c(20,40))
```

The above line tests whether the trend of `nitro` is different between 20° and 40° in variety A. I picked 20° and 40° arbitrarily; a common choice is $mean-SD$ and $mean+SD$, or the medians of the first and third terciles.

Comment: Thanks @Ous, your answer was helpful. However can't you have a regression slope for each categorical predictor that reflects the relationship between the continuous predictors and the DV? For example, I can imagine a regression line in which the `DV` is in y axis, `nitro` in x axis and `temp` in z axis. Each `variety` would then get its own slope in this 3D plane. It would then just be a matter of comparing the slope for `variety A` with the slope for `variety B` for example

Comment: I think this might be possible to test with the `summary()` function if the contrasts are done right, but I thought it would be easier with `emtrends` somehow.

Comment: Actually you would get a 2D plane for the interaction, not a line. The slope of it would be of dimension 2, and I have no idea how you might contrasts such slopes.
Imagine you had a 3-way interaction with categorical variables. How would you proceed for post hoc tests using `emmeans`?

Comment: You are right, it would be a plane not a line. But if you look at the output of `summary(mod)` you get
`varietyB:nitro:temp  ... 1.75    0.09`
I read this like: how different is the `nitro:temp` interaction for `varietyB` from the `nitro:temp` interaction for `varietyA` (the reference). So here you could potentially calculate whether this interaction is significantly different between the two varieties. Or am I misunderstanding this output?

Comment: Also, the code you provided returns the same `t.ratio` and `p.value` regardless of what contrast I specify. Changing the code from `at=list(variety="A", temp=c(20,40))` to `at=list(variety="A", temp=c(20,30))` results in the same `t.ratio` and `p.value`